# In dialog box "setCanceledOnTouchOutside()" not working to cancel the box

Tags: android, dialog

Okay so i made a dialog :

```
package com.dharamshi.practice;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewDialog {

    public void showDialog(Activity activity, String msg){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_dialog);
        text.setText(msg);

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog);
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();

    }
}
```

And i want the dialog to dismiss itself when its clicked on the area outside the dialog.

I also added the setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true) but it just won't work.

What changes should i make to get it to work ?

I called it in this way :

```
ViewDialog alert = new ViewDialog();
alert.showDialog(this, "Its Working!");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a small but silly mistake,

Comment out

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

because to if you want the dialog to dismiss when you click outside the dialog area how do you expect it to when you have set the cancelable property to false.

change it and it will work!

Answer (score 2):

**dialog.setCancelable(false)** does not allow to cancel the dialog. Thats why **dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)** is not showing any effect.

So remove **dialog.setCancelable(false)**  from your code.

Answer (score 2):

if you got a style for your dialog just add this attribute.

```
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
```

to your style, and if you don't have any style, Apply a custom style to your dialog and add this attribute to it.
for example :

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparentDark</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/fade_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/fade_out</item>

    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/statusBarColor</item>
</style>
```

and then use it like this:

Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity, R.style.DialogTheme);
        dialog.getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.style.DialogTheme);

Answer (score 1):

> I also added the `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)` but it just won't work.

The `setCanceledOnTouchOutside()` is not working because you have added **`setCancelable(false)`**  property to your `dialog` which means you `dialog` will not dismiss when you click outside the `dialog` or press the back button key

### Solution

You need to Remove **`dialog.setCancelable(false);`** From your `showDialog()` method

[**`setCancelable()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setCancelable(boolean))

> Sets whether the `dialog` is **cancelable or not**. **Default is true**.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
public class ViewDialog {

    public void showDialog(Activity activity, String msg){
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_dialog);
        text.setText(msg);

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog);
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();

    }
}
```