# Created a custom layout dialog, but not able to dismiss dialog when clicked outside dialog window

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-styles, android-windowmanager

```
        **Please help me out where I have done wrong**
```

> I am not able to dismiss dialog when clicked on the outside area on my
> screen only dismissed when I press backpress in mobile keys.

```
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_child_product_two);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
        lp.dimAmount = 0.7f; // Dim level. 0.0 - no dim, 1.0 - completely opaque
        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        
        *// Views inflated in my dialog to perform some actions on keypress*
        Button btnDone = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_done);
       
        btnDone.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            // Do some work here after some action performed
            dialog.dismiss();
        });
        dialog.show();
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're calling `setCancelable(false)` if you want it to be cancelled when you touch outside the dialog?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In dialog box "setCanceledOnTouchOutside()" not working to cancel the box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726634/in-dialog-box-setcanceledontouchoutside-not-working-to-cancel-the-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);
```

I have tried removing the style from this dialog
and added the following :

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Or

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Both working fine and able to dismiss the dialog on the outside area click.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

because to if you want the dialog to dismiss when you click outside the dialog area how do you expect it to when you have set the cancelable property to false.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51726668/9972209)